What is the fractal dimension of 2D Brownian motion?
I have a question regarding the numerical evaluation of the fractal (Hausdorff) dimension of 2D Brownian walkers on a square lattice.
The fractal dimension is known to be 2 (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension).
The typical method used in these situations is box-counting (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_counting).
I have implemented said method in Mathematica and when checking against known values I obtain reasonable agreement with the expectations for:
Uniform Random Points -> 2
KochCurve -> 1.27
Sierpinski triangle -> 1.58
Sierpinski carpet -> 1.89
However, when I apply it to a 2D Brownian motion walker I obtain ~1.70-1.75 for the fractal dimension.
I tried to google for references that have performed this type of calculation and the only one I found is https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.11625, and similarly reports a number that is not 2.
How to account for this obvious discrepancy?
An graphical example of a single Brownian motion:

